# How to replace all non-alphanumeric of any languages?

Tags: regex, go

Using regex in golang, I'd like to replace all non-alphanumeric characters of any languages with `-`, in order to make pretty urls:

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/CTPw2W13GlP) is one of many regex that I've tried:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

const sample = `سلام دنیا hello world 1 %^&`

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`~[\p{L}0-9\s]+`)
    s := re.ReplaceAllString(sample, `-`)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

The output should be:
`سلام-دنیا-hello-world-1`

But it does not work. How can I fix it?

Comment: First you'll have to define exactly what you mean by "non-alphanumeric of any language." Not all languages even use an alphabet in writing, such as Chinese. Do you want to convert all Chinese writing to `-`? Or do you just want to preserve the undecorated Latin alphabet?

Comment: Well, I don't care about Chinese/Japanese/Korean and so on. The languages that concern me are European, Arabic and Persian which are either left-to-right or right-to-left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use `~` at the beginning? If you want to se negated set, use `^` inside of the brackets: `[^...]`. Also if you want to replace whitespaces, don't include `\s` in the negated set definition:

```
[^\p{L}0-9]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ydHeBf/2/)

Comment: The regex should also convert space to `-` so what I was looking for is `[^\p{L}0-9\s]+|[\040]`. Please update and I'll accept. Thanks

Comment: Why not `[^\p{L}0-9]+` without space in excluded set?

Comment: As I said, I'd like to make slugs out of the strings, so spaces need to be replaced with `-`.

Comment: Like this: https://regex101.com/r/ydHeBf/2/? I think see what you mean, but I think we could use a simpler regex here :)

Comment: Right, this is more elegant!

Comment: Edited, take a look